# Error when install ECB with emacs 24.3.1

Tags: emacs, emacs24, emacs-ecb

I'm trying to install ECB to use with Emacs 24.3.1 using Emacs Package Manager but I got this error when installing:

```
Compiling file /home/khanh/.emacs.d/elpa/ecb-20130406.1406/ecb2/jn-file-tree.el at Mon Jul  1 20:54:45 2013
Entering directory `/home/khanh/.emacs.d/elpa/ecb-20130406.1406/ecb2/'
jn-file-tree.el:31:1:Error: Cannot open load file: jn-tree-node

Compiling file /home/khanh/.emacs.d/elpa/ecb-20130406.1406/ecb2/jn-tree-node.el at Mon Jul  1 20:54:45 2013
jn-tree-node.el:32:1:Error: Cannot open load file: jn-utils

Compiling file /home/khanh/.emacs.d/elpa/ecb-20130406.1406/ecb2/jn-tree-view.el at Mon Jul  1 20:54:45 2013
jn-tree-view.el:31:1:Error: Cannot open load file: jn-window

Compiling file /home/khanh/.emacs.d/elpa/ecb-20130406.1406/ecb2/jn-utils.el at Mon Jul  1 20:54:45 2013

Compiling file /home/khanh/.emacs.d/elpa/ecb-20130406.1406/ecb2/jn-window.el at Mon Jul  1 20:54:45 2013
jn-window.el:44:25:Error: Invalid lambda variable (parent jn-window-container)

Compiling file /home/khanh/.emacs.d/elpa/ecb-20130406.1406/ecb2/test.el at Mon Jul  1 20:54:45 2013
test.el:31:1:Error: Cannot open load file: jn-tree-view
```

Any body help me please. Thank you.
Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Well, this looks like the package failed to list the dependency on `jn-utils`. You could probably try to check it out from here: https://github.com/alexott/ecb/tree/master/ecb2 or write to the maintainer and ask him to fix it. Alex is often reading SO posts in this thread, so maybe he'll comment.

Comment: I have this problem, too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing ECB in emacs 24 in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847874/installing-ecb-in-emacs-24-in-ubuntu)

Comment: It's answered here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847874/installing-ecb-in-emacs-24-in-ubuntu